# Value counts for two columns inside the same table

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to count values in two columns and then put the results in the same table.

```
dict = { "before": list("ABCDEFABDCFEFF"),
         "after" : list("FABFCFFEEDEBFF") }

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Output

```
   before after
0       A     F
1       B     A
2       C     B
3       D     F
4       E     C
5       F     F
6       A     F
7       B     E
8       D     E
9       C     D
10      F     E
11      E     B
12      F     F
13      F     F
```

I've achieved something close to what I want, but this looks messy, and I'm hoping for a "smoother" solution.

```
df.melt().groupby("variable")["value"].value_counts().to_frame().unstack()
```

Output:

```
         value               
value        A  B  C  D  E  F
variable                     
after        1  2  1  1  3  6
before       2  2  2  2  2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
```

Comment: Of course it was this easy :)

Comment: Is this basically the same as this: `pd.concat([df["before"].value_counts(), df["after"].value_counts()], axis=1)` ?

Comment: Yes except the index will not be sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `before` and `after` as the row indexes as shown in your current output, you should use the following.

`df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).transpose()`

Answer (score 0):

A different way with `melt` using `pivot_table`:

```
>>> df.melt().assign(count=1).pivot_table('count', 'variable', 'value', aggfunc='count')

value     A  B  C  D  E  F
variable                  
after     1  2  1  1  3  6
before    2  2  2  2  2  4
```